# Changing a Setter Value Dynamically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, charts

I am trying to change a setter value dynamically. Even though I am successful partially, stuck with progressing further. My attempt is to change the column colours of a wpf toolkit generated column chart depending on the series. I used a static member of a separate class to set the color of the background property of the column data point. In this way only the finally assigned color gets set to all the columns regardless of they being different series. Following are the useful code spinets:

Column datapoint style is defined with the following xaml:

```
<local:MyBackColor x:Key="mybackresource"></local:MyBackColor>
<Style x:Key="InfocruiserAquaColumn" TargetType="DVC:ColumnDataPoint">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource mybackresource}, Path= myBackColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />...
```

Class which sets the color:

```
public class MyBackColor {
    private static String _myBackColor;


    public static String myBackColor
    {
        get { return _myBackColor; }

        set
        {
            _myBackColor = value;
            //Helpers.InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChanged, this, "Grade");
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the color in code:

```
 //Changing the column color
                MyBackColor.myBackColor = colorValue;

                myStyle = (Style)FindResource("InfocruiserAquaColumn");

                ColumnSeries myColumnSeries = new ColumnSeries();
                myColumnSeries.Title = "Experience";

                myColumnSeries.ItemsSource = seriesData;

                myColumnSeries.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key");
                myColumnSeries.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value");
                myColumnSeries.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);


                myColumnSeries.DataPointStyle = myStyle;

                mcChart.Series.Add(myColumnSeries);
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for the quick response. Problem is when I want to create two series I with two different colors I simply can not do it dynamically. Only the finally assigned color to myBackColor gets assigned as the color for all the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need both the NotifyPropertyChange (why is it commented out?) and to make the Background a DynamicResource:

```
<Setter Property="Background" 
      Value="{Binding Source={DynamicResource mybackresource}, Path= myBackColor}"/>
```

---

After the comments:

Your current solution is not going to work. When you execute

```
   myColumnSeries.DataPointStyle = myStyle;
```

you are only storing a reference to the style, not a copy. So all Series still share the same Style (the last one).

You'll have to use something like (incomplete answer ahead):

```
myColumnSeries.DataPointStyle = new Style();
myColumnSeries.DataPointStyle.Background = ...
```

Or maybe you can set just the Color of the Series and use a shared Style for the other properties.

Comment: Hi Henk, Thanks for your prompt answer. I am new to wpf and don't quite understand setting NotifyPropertyChange and making it work in this context to get my problem solved. Could you explain me a bit about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Henk, I get the following error when I set the source property to Dynamic: A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'Binding'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject'. What should I do about this?

Comment: Hi Henk, Thanks again for your valuable input. I will try playing around with the code to get things working. Additionally I think you can find that I am using a template to set the column data point style and would be inconvenient to do the entire thing in the code. But as you explain separating the background property, I guess, should work. I will try. Thanks